# Problem with URLs on pages being served as XHTML

Tags: xml, url, xhtml, hyperlink

The following link to a URL in my application is giving me an XML Parsing Error on the second equals sign when I try to view the page.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/admin/banning.php?do=banuser&u=3">Ban User</a>
```

I think the problem is the ampersand in the URL. If I encode the ampersand the parsing error goes away but the URL no longer functions. Is there an easy way to get URLs like this to work in a page being served as XHTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encoding the ampersand is the correct way. If the URL doesn't work, something else must be wrong.

Comment: What I don't get is that pasting the URL into my browser gets the correct result yet when I encode the ampersand using %26 it breaks.

Comment: %26 is URL encoded. &amp; is XML encoded - hence why the latter works.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `&amp;` instead of `&` in any xhtml-document